# Calling exec() on php

Tags: php

I can't see why exec() doesn't run on RaspberryPi but it outputs 'something'.
Can someone please help me?

```
<?php
echo exec('GPIO.Output 1 1');  
echo('something');  
?>
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Is GPIO.Output an actual executable? Does it work from the command line? Does the PHP user have permission to run it? Does the webserver user have permission to access the files in /proc/ that GPIO manipulating programs need to write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec()` returns only last line of executed command's output. Use [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead.

Alternatively you can make use of seconde `exec()` argument which like:

```
$output = array();
exec('GPIO.Output 1 1', $output);  // $output is passed by reference
```

Now `$output` contains command's output with every line as a separate array element

Answer (score 1):

Remove exec from the disabled functions in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.
I used the system() function insted, and it worked.
Here is the code:

`

$last_line = system('/var/www/pornire_bec.cgi', $retval);

echo '
Last Line: ' . $last_line . '
Return Value: ' . $retval;
?>`